# MySQl log in issue when changing @localhost to IP address

Tags: mysql

I created a user called 'test1' with all all the privileges, but I changed the host name to be my ip address instead of localhost. I was able to login and create a connection using MySQL WorkBench just fine. However I can not login using terminal because it adds @localhost by default each time I try to login. As you can see the below error, it is adding @'localhost' by default. Am I doing something wrong here? FYi, I am doing all the logging on my local machine and my password is correct since I use using workbench just as fine.

mysql -u 'test1'@'xxx.xxx.x.xx' -p (login command)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test1@xxx.xxx.x.xx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way of login command when one has a user with host name other than localhost.

mysql -h xxx.xxx.x.xx -u test1 -p